# alphanumeric in resturl in yii framework

Tags: php, regex, url-rewriting, yii

I have created RESTful webservice in Yii Framework in which for url mapping there is an entry in main.php config file

```
'api/<controller:\w+>/<id:\w+>'=>array('<controller>/restView', 'verb'=>'GET')
```

But this url allow to map only id having numerical values for example it allows only 101 ,102 ets but not m101,m102 so what should i do so that it allows alphanumeric characters too.

for instance rite now it allows

> api/getAllInfo/101  -- allows
>
> api/getAllInfo/m101 -- does not allow

**EDIT**

```
'api/<controller:\w+>'=>array('<controller>/calendarList/?$', 'verb'=>'GET'),
            'api/<controller:\w+>'=>array('<controller>/restList/?$', 'verb'=>'GET'),
            'api/<controller:\w+>/<id:\w+>'=>array('<controller>/restView', 'verb'=>'GET'),
            'api/<controller:\w+>/<id:\w+>/<var:\w+>'=>array('<controller>/restView', 'verb'=>'GET'),
            array('<controller>/restUpdate', 'pattern'=>'api/<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>', 'verb'=>'PUT'),
            array('<controller>/restDelete', 'pattern'=>'api/<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>', 'verb'=>'DELETE'),
            array('<controller>/restCreate', 'pattern'=>'api/<controller:\w+>', 'verb'=>'POST'),
            array('<controller>/restCreate', 'pattern'=>'api/<controller:\w+>/<id:\w+>', 'verb'=>'POST'),


            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
```

Comment: `\w` is a synonym for `[0-9a-zA-Z_]` (and maybe hyphen) or alphanumeric. I suppose, that problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: agree with kirilloid there's definitely some other problem. can you put up the rest of the urlRules? maybe some other rule is conflicting.